# Ruby, Sinatra, Overriding/Extending a class from a separate file to add a method

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm new to Ruby, I can find answers for various variations on this question but not an answer to my problem itself.

I am writing an application which takes basic auth details and uses them to authenticate the user with a 3rd party platform as such I need to be able to access the password in order to pass it on **but** I also want to be able to use the Rack Authentication classes

All I want to do is this:

```
require 'rack/auth/abstract/request'
require 'rack/auth/basic'

class AuthRequest < Rack::Auth::Basic::Request < Rack::Auth::AbstractRequest
    def password
      credentials[1]
    end
end
```

If I use `Request < Auth::AbstractRequest` the IDE tells me I have undeclare constant, but if I fully qualify it as above it says 'wrong argument type true (expected Class) (TypeError)'

I read various articles including [this](http://tech.tulentsev.com/2012/02/ruby-how-to-override-class-method-with-a-module/) but I'm no less confused, I think the problem stems from the fact I'm trying to extend a subclass from this external file, not it's root class.

What's the right way to do this?

**Edit** - some more information on my requirement:
I'm basing this need on this sample from the Sinatra documentation. I want the `@auth` object for the niceness like `provided?` and `basic?` but as I can't simply do a comparison like `@auth.credentials == ['admin', 'admin']`, I need access to the password, which is not granted in the default implementation

```
helpers do 

  ...

  def authorized?
    @auth ||=  Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(request.env)
    @auth.provided? && @auth.basic? && @auth.credentials && @auth.credentials == ['admin', 'admin']
  end

end
```

Comment: Before trying to override anything I suggest you to read about the basics about [inheritance](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Defining+a+class) in Ruby. What do you think `class AuthRequest < Rack::Auth::Basic::Request < Rack::Auth::AbstractRequest` actually means?

Comment: That's what I thought I explained above - that my AuthRequest class should inherit from the Request Class. Your link seems to support that idea `class MySubclass < MyClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you expect the expression `class AuthRequest < Rack::Auth::Basic::Request < Rack::Auth::AbstractRequest` to behave, maybe some kind of multiple inheritance?

The problem here is that, being `Rack::Auth::Basic::Request` a subclass of `Rack::Auth::AbstractRequest`, the expression `Rack::Auth::Basic::Request < Rack::Auth::AbstractRequest` evaluates to `true` (see [`Module#<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-3C)), thus your expression is actually interpreted as `class AuthRequest < true`, that makes no sense, hence the `TypeError`.

If I got right what you are trying to achieve the following code should do:

```
class AuthRequest < Rack::Auth::Basic::Request
  def password
    credentials[1]
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah ok, the first error message I received made me think I needed to include the whole hierarchy